# Focus on next form Input using focus() function

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am using **typescript** with react native and I don't know if I define my input ref type right or not.

Here is the relevant part of my code: (both components are my custom components, the `TextInput` is not for react-native.)

```
// in begin of class
private readonly passwordInputRef: React.RefObject<Password> = createRef();

// in render function
<TextInput
    key={'login page username'}
    language={language}
    placeholder={'Username:'}
    value={username}
    containerStyle={styles.username}
    hasError={loginError}
    onChangeText={this.setUsername}
    returnKeyType={"next"}
    blurOnSubmit={false}
    onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInputRef.current!.focus()} />
<Password
    key={'login page password'}
    ref={this.passwordInputRef}
    language={language}
    placeholder={'Password:'}
    value={password}
    containerStyle={styles.password}
    hasError={loginError}
    onChangeText={this.setPassword}/>
```

when I run application and press next button on keyboard it gives me an error `_this.passwordInputRef.current.focus is not a function`

I have search and read many answers on stackoverflow, but none of them don't explain how it's work with typescript.

Also I read this [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19824), it's seems my codes is very similar to that, except I'm using typescript, so I think there is a problem with my define command for `passwordInputRef`.

What I am doing wrong?

currently I'm using:

```
"react": "16.5.2"
"react-native": "0.55.2"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem. in `Password` component class I define a ref object with react-native `TextInput` type,

```
// in begin of Password class
private readonly inputRef: React.RefObject<TextInput> = createRef();
```

and then set this reference object to inner TextInput in render method:

```
// other views
<TextInput
    {...this.props}
    ref={this.inputRef} <----
    key={'password value input'}
    secureTextEntry={hidePassword}
    />
// other views
```

and define a `focus` method for class just like below:

```
public focus() {
  this.inputRef.current && this.inputRef.current.focus();
}
```

no need to change anything else, it works perfectly.

if I understand correctly, the procedure should be like below:

- when you custom an input, you need to handle focus yourself.
- the code in my question, call `focus` method of `Password` component
- I must forward focus to my inner input component